# how get raw value of angular attribute directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I want to retrieve the raw value of a directive attribute but it keeps retrieveing the literal attribute name instead of the raw value

--HTML

```
<input my-directive="5==5" />
<div my-directive="isFoodReady()">
  <!--some content-->
</div>
```

--JS

```
myModule.directive('myDirective',function(){
    restrict: 'A',
    priority: 0,
    link:function(scope,element,attr){
         console.log(attr.myDirective);
         //displays "5==5","isFoodReady()" instead of true
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you create fiddle or codepen to debug easily?

Comment: Why wouldn't you just evaluate this in controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, it's working

```js
angular.module('app', [])
  .directive('myDirective', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      priority: 0,
      link: function(scope, element, attr) {
        console.log(eval(attr.myDirective));
      }
    }
  });

function isFoodReady() {
  return true;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
<input my-directive="5==5" />
<div my-directive="isFoodReady()">
  <!--some content-->
</div>
</div>
```

Keep in mind using eval is **extremely dangerous** and a terrible practice overall. You shouldn't be running javascript off a directive's attribute since it leaves your code open to even the simples of code injection techniques.

I highly recommend you visit https://xss-game.appspot.com/ to see what I mean

Comment: what if the function is inside a a controller? like $scope.isFoodReady = function(){return true;}

Comment: That's another question entirely since you asked how to get the evaluated value from the directive attributes, not how to execute a controller's function from a directive. Anyways, if what you are seeking is directive/controller communication, this might help: http://jsfiddle.net/simpulton/geaab/

Comment: I suggest that if my or Rohit's answers successfully solve your question, you mark it as accepted and make another question about "how to communicate directive to controller" if you are still having issues.

Answer (score 0):

try `console.log(eval(attr.myDirective));`

Comment: do I need to inject something to use the eval() function?

Comment: its javascript function. No need for any injection